# A word to say "the company has various merits"?

Tags: word-choice

*The company has various merits. For example, it is a company that gives its employees high freedom.*

I want to know what is the word to use in this context. Candidate words I've found are *pros*, *strengths*, and *virtue*.

Comment: Yes, *merits* is fine. Of the alternatives, *pros* means the same thing but in a less formal register, *strengths* is also good but has more connotations of "being good at something" than "something good about the company", though can and does carry both meanings, and *virtues* is also an apt choice.

Comment: I think you can say 'The company is highly qualified'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Merits" is the best choice, I would say.

Another way, more common, but with slightly different choice of words, would be:

> The company provides various benefits.

The benefits can be for the employees (e.g. free lunch) or for the community where it operates (e.g. supporting a shelter of some kind), can be material (e.g. money) or non-material (e.g. flexible schedule)...

However, the variant using "benefits" tells less than the variant with "merits". For example, a company can have the merit to discover something, but that is not a provided benefit.